# Capacitated Maximum Coverage Location Problem, Python and Gurobi

Tags: optimization, python, integer-programming, gurobi

I am trying to solve a capacitated MCLP problem with two additional constraints.

1. Non-overlapping circles
2. Minimum and Maximum value for the capacity for a circle.

for 2nd constraint, I am able to add maximum limit but I am getting error when I try to add the minimum limit (as some locations are zeros and cannot be selected)

All the details are same as this question. [Capacitated Maximum Coverage Location Problem, Python and Gurobi](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/capacitated-maximum-coverage-location-problem-python-and-gurobi/9676#9676) and I found it useful for adding a constraint.

Pls suggest how can I add the second constraint?

Note: Below image is added for the added query i.e not all demand points from a location, were included in the optimized solution. pls see the query in detail below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are looking for something like
$Minpoints\cdot x_j \le \sum_{i \in\ S_j} y_i \ \ \forall j \in\ J$
where $x_j =1$ if Facility j is selected at all, $S_j =\{i \in\ I: d_{i,j} \le r\}$ and Minpoints is a number you choose

Using same code as before

```
for j in J:
 model.addConstr(minpoints*x[j] <= quicksum(y[i] for i in np.where(D[:,j]==1)[0]))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141922/discussion-on-answer-by-sutanu-capacitated-maximum-coverage-location-problem-py).

Answer (score 1):

Code with Sample data:\

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from collections import namedtuple
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix as dm

N =15 #Sites" Towers
R = 86
#Generate Data
Points = namedtuple('Points', 'x, y')
def gen_data(Points,N):
  locations = []
  for p in range(N):
    x,y = np.random.uniform(1,10,size = 2)
    points = Points(x,y)
    if points.x**2 + points.y**2 <= R**2:
      locations.append(points)
  return np.array([[p.x,p.y] for p in locations],dtype='float16')
  #return sites
#print(sites)
#Generate sites
sites = gen_data(Points,N)

towers = gen_data(Points,7)
#print(towers)

N,_ = sites.shape
I = [*range(N)]
T,_ = towers.shape
J = [*range(T)]
K = 5
maxpoints = 13 #per tower circle
minpoints = 2 #per tower circle
#Generate distance D(i,j)
D = dm(sites,towers).astype('float16')
print(D)
#Masking
mask = (D < 7)
D[mask] = 1; D[~mask]=0

model = Model('fac')

x = model.addVars(J,vtype='b',name='x')
y = model.addVars(I,vtype='b',name='y')

C1 = model.addConstr(x.sum() == K,'C1')
C2 = model.addConstrs((minpoints*x[j] <= quicksum(y[i] for i in np.where(D[:,j]==1)[0])\
                      for j in J),'C2')

#C3 = model.addConstrs((quicksum(x[j] for j in np.where(D[i,:]==1)[0])<= K*(1-y[i])+y[i]\
 #                     for i in I),'NonOverlapping')

                  for j in J),'C2')
C5 = model.addConstrs((maxpoints >= quicksum(y[i] for i in np.where(D[:,j]==1)[0])\
                      for j in J),'C2')    
C4 = model.addConstrs((y[i] == 1 for i in np.where(np.sum(D,axis=1)>=1)[0]),'C4')
obj = y.sum()
model.setObjective(obj,GRB.MAXIMIZE)
model.update()
model.optimize()
model.printAttr('x')
```

Comment: Thank you Sutanu for showing the path. In your code, y[i] ==1 seems to work for allocating all demand points. But I think the problem comes when max capacity constraint is added because it just caps inclusion beyond the max limit and then y[i] cannot be one for that demand point. I have added the max capacity constraint like this -> for j in range(J):
        
        m.addConstr(quicksum(int(a[i])*y[i] for i in np.where(D[:,j]==1)[0]) <= 32)                     please tweak your code. Sorry I am getting error when I am trying to add it in your code.

Comment: Lets make it the last comment, otherwise moderator will remove. See you are not assigning any location to site like $x_{i,j}$. Here selecting demand sites & facilities are kind of independent variables. So when you are putting a max point basically you are selecting a subset of $y$ and constraining it. So if any $y_i = 1$ for one subset of $x$ it remains 1 for the other Xs, in a way restricting total number of Ys you are selecting. Otherwise you need to you 2-D variable like $x_{i,j}$